Machloket On Conversion
I did a conversion with Rabbi Eliyahu Ben Haim (Mekor Haim Beit Din in Queens). Rabbi Eliyahu Ben Haim, Rabbi Binyamin Golan, and Rabbi Yitzchak Abramov were the witnesses. With that being said, although the conversion was kosher, it has come to my attention that there are “doubts.” Eliyahu Ben Haim was a personal student of Haham Ovadia Yosef, Rabbi Ben Zion Abba Shaul, and Rabbi Ezra Attiya or veshalom. He is also the chief rabbi in charge of all the marriages and divorces for the Sephardic community in New York. He supervises the a badatz beit Yosef hechsher in New York. He also is involved with a kollel, teaches at Yeshiva University, and is the chief rabbi for the Persian community in Great Neck.
I was told by certain Litvish, Chabad, and Ashkenazi rabbis that they cannot rely on it. If it was an halachic conversion I don’t understand what the issue is. Is this a racist issue? Do the ashkenazim not recognize the Sephardim? Rabbi Akivas 24,000 stufents died because they had no respect for each others Torah. Sounds like a similar situation. Can someone please help me understand the situation. Thank you.

Gavriel, you should ask the people who thought not to rely on it what their issue is. We can't know, but there is undoubtedly nothing related to Sefardi/Ashkenazi at play here, even if one internet user below likes to imagine self-victimed racism at every possible turn.

Welcome to MiYodeya Gavriel and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us! No worries, we love Sefaradim on this site, and some of us love them so much we married one of them.

This question lacks details about the alleged "doubts" regarding the conversions performed by this Beit Din, and proof of any "Machloket on Conversion". Questions based on phantom hearsay, do not belong in this forum.

I'd be happier if the question did not include statements about racism, and comparison to Rabbi Akiva's students. Find out what the issue was, if any, and get back to us.

The Rabbinical Council of America has guidelines for acceptable conversions and beit dins. It could be that your beit din didn't follow these rules so and RCA Rabbi won't accept your conversion. It could be a matter as simple as a Rabbi not paying membership dues.

Conversion in the USA is clearly a controversial topic. This resource on Sefaria:
sefaria.org/sheets/58807?lang=bi  Conversion in America:  Historical and Halakhic Perspectives
collects some source materials and, as the title suggests, provides both a historical and a halakhic perspective which addresses general issues. The issues which potentially arise with conversion in the USA can best be understood by gaining an understanding of the overall picture rather than focusing on any individual case. It is against that background that I have tried to address issues that the OP has raised.
It is puzzling that doubts are raised about a conversion conducted by Rabbi Eliyahu Ben Chaim as his name הרב אליהו בן חיים and beth din appears on the list of "a limited number of conversion courts outside of Israel" recognised by the Israel Chief Rabbinate which can be found [2019 version] on the website of ITIM https://www.itim.org.il at https://www.itim.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/רשימת-בתי-דין-לגיור-בעולם.pdf
Rabbi Eliyahu Ben Chaim is a Yeshiva University faculty member and is shown as such on the YU website Rabbi Eliyahu Ben-Haim, Maxwell R. Maybaum Memorial Chair in Talmud and Sephardic Codes (Halacha) https://www.yu.edu/riets/faculty
Details of the Mekor Haim Beit Din in Queens can be found at https://www.badatzqueens.org and details of its conversion programme at https://www.badatzqueens.org/conversion
See also this article in HaModia which discusses the Edict of the Syrian Jewish community. The Edict, which forbids accepting converts, and under which children born from a marriage to a convert are prohibited from marrying into the Syrian community has both attracted criticism and been passionately defended over the years since 1935 when it was first enacted. The article enables the reader to gain a better understanding of another specific conversion-related issue to achieve some perspective on and insight into questions raised by conversion generally.
The question does not provide any specific details about claims made. [The OP writes: it has come to my attention that there are “doubts.” and I was told by certain Litvish, Chabad, and Ashkenazi rabbis that they cannot rely on it ] It is a good practice between different communities to resolve doubts by communication. Specifically, if there is a doubt regarding a conversion, the rabbi raising the doubt should contact the rabbi of the convert or the Beis Din to resolve any misunderstanding.[Edit by Y DJ, bracketed wording inserted by Edward B]
